# Volume controller and screen size controller missing from Youtube app

Tags: youtube

I have Samsung P-3100 Tab. I have youtube android application installed. I am having the following complaints with youtube player (Probably I do not know how to  get to these, so this question! )

1) If I hold the Tab in Landscape orientation, then the video occupies the whole screen (which is as expected). However, I cannot see the screen size icon on the screen, to change the screen size from "Full Screen" to normal screen Mode. I have to rotate the Tab to Vertical orientation to see see any comments or related videos. (this is very annoying!) :(

2) There is no volume controller on the screen anywhere. Is it because youtube app rely on the volume controller on the Tab?

I am sure other people might have faced the same issue. I googled for this issue but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. If you bear this in mind next time you have several related questions, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a non-fullscreen layout for YouTube for 7in tablets, only for 10in tablets. There's no button there because there's nothing to switch to. The developers evidently think there's not enough room to see the video and display other information usefully at the same time.

You're right about the volume control. Because Android already has separate volume settings for media, notifications, and the phone ringer, and it guarantees the presence of hardware volume controls, it's considered bad design to put additional volume controls on the screen.